# Connect a db-visualization program to db running on homestead win

Tags: database, laravel-5, homestead

I have everything up and running nicely on my windows machine. I do homestead and VM. My database is all there and i can log on to it in the terminal. But as the tutorial says I want a db visualization program. Jeff is suggesting sequelPro but it is only for mac... I have looked around and found DBeaver to look really good. So I am good there. Now to my problem:

I am trying to connect with the data from the .env file:

DB_CONNECTION=mysql

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

DB_PORT=3306

DB_DATABASE=blog

DB_USERNAME=root

DB_PASSWORD=secret

This is from DBeaver: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDRYB.png

Don't know which local client thats right but I have tried the mall and nothing works. Get this when I connect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8jYN.jpg

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from another forum:

User Cronix in the Laracast forum:
You're trying to connect to the wrong port. port 3306 from WITHIN homestead (like your laravel app), port 33060 to connect remotely from OUTSIDE homestead (your host OS - windows).

```
To connect to your MySQL or Postgres database from your host machine's 
database client, you should connect to 127.0.0.1 and port 33060 (MySQL) or 
54320 (Postgres). The username and password for both databases is homestead 
/ secret.
```